# Mypy raises "Cannot assign multiple types" when defining type in if else

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

In our tests we test for multiple versions of numpy. The older versions don't have certain classes (`np.random.Generator`) which we want to define in our typing, so I chose to define the type based on checking the numpy version:

```py
# random generator
if np_version_under1p17:
    RandomState = Union[int, ArrayLike, np.random.RandomState]
else:
    RandomState = Union[int, ArrayLike, np.random.Generator, np.random.RandomState]
```

But this results in:

```
Cannot assign multiple types to name "RandomState" without an explicit "Type[...]" annotation
```

While removing the `if .. else` resolves this error:

```py
RandomState = Union[int, ArrayLike, np.random.Generator, np.random.RandomState]
```

But then our tests with old numpy versions will fail.

What is the best way to define `RandomState`, but define it in such a way so it will both work for newer and older numpy versions in our tests.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a variable to have a different compile-time type depending on a check you are doing at runtime.

Comment: I agree, but I was not sure how to solve it in a different way.

Comment: There's always the "don't annotate that" option. I feel like this option is severely underrated.

Comment: That is what I will go for, too many complications for an annotation. @user2357112supportsMonica